# Detect if monitor is on c#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to detect if the users monitor is turned on using c#?

Comment: Do you mean using the power button on the front, or auto-switch-off for power saving?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

WMI might help.

In Vista+, there is the [WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394535(v=VS.85).aspx) class, where the "Active" property tells you if the display is active.

Here's an example which works for me:

```
using System.Management;

// ...

var query = "select * from WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams";
using(var wmiSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("\\root\\wmi", query))
{
    var results = wmiSearcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject wmiObj in results)
    {
        // get the "Active" property and cast to a boolean, which should 
        // tell us if the display is active. I've interpreted this to mean "on"
        var active = (Boolean)wmiObj["Active"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I never cease to be amazed by the sheer amount of info hidden in WMI.

Comment: Some old displays connected via VGA cable are generally dumb device, as they report only 'connected' and EDID info. NO power state is present; what changed in new displays so they can tell?

Comment: Does this really work? If I run the code against switched off monitor it still shows active = true. Tried on both VGA and DVI types. Maybe my monitors are just dumb...

Comment: This doesn't work with any of my monitors, connected via VGA, DVI and HDMI. It always returns true for all 3.

Comment: Same here, when Windows switches the monitors into power-saving mode, "Active" is still true.

Answer (score 4):

All the Active property does is tell you if Windows is using the display or not. Also DVI/HDMI will report a connection even when the display is turned off. In short, there is no method for checking other than something homemade--like hooking up a light sensor or webcam and pointing it at the monitor's power light :)