# Automatically detect whether there is a projector connected to a computer

Tags: c#, projector

I want to write a program to automatically detect whether there is a projector connected to a computer, and whether the projector is open? I don't know how to do this. Could you give me some suggestions on how to do it. I use the C# language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could check if another display is connected? Im not sure but you may be able to get details from the display and see if it is a projector.

Possibly check out these links:

[How to detect if additional monitor is connected and active](http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?example=542&ver=vcs)

It looks like WMI might be the way, [Detect if monitor is on c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913025/detect-if-monitor-is-on-c-sharp)

Comment: sorry , I haven't said very clearly. I want to know how many displays are on dual clone. The all displays are in the same view.